# issues with porting a DLL C++ class library to Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, export

I wrote a class library in C++ and successfully compiled it in Linux with g++ as a shared object, then created a few apps that use it. Now I have to port it to VS2008. I gave all the classes the required __declspec(dllexport) prefixes, then tried to compile it. I get a pile of warnings, which basically have to do with:

1. my custom exception classes, derived from std::runtime_error, which yield:
   "warning C4275: non dll-interface class 'std::runtime_error' used as base for dll-interface class 'cci::FileOperationException'". How am I supposed to make a standard library class dll-exportable?
2. exception specifications in member functions' declarations, which cause "warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)". I read somewhere that VS doesn't support these, and that it does somewhere else. How very confusing.

I read people saying that exporting classes in a DLL is generally a Bad Idea, that there's a myriad of things that can go wrong, and now I have my head full of concepts like binary incompatibility, dll hell, compiler version mismatches etc, and to be honest I can't really make heads or tails of it. What is the correct, safe and easy way to create a shared class library in Windows, then?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it really need to be a DLL? Making a static library will avoid lots of problems.

Comment: Good point. :) The original question still stands, though - people are able to use DLLs somehow, aren't they? (Also, any easy way to change the build from shared to static? Will Project->Properties->General->Configuration Type->Static Library be enough?)

Comment: They are using them, but not without a lot of hoop jumping. IMHO, a static library should always be the first choice.

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: As I didn't fail to mention - it is VS2008 Professional. Why? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maintain [a C++ class library](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/) that is typically used as DLL on Windows, so it can be done.  Regarding your issues:

1. That doesn't happen in my library.  Perhaps you need to be using the /MD and /MDd build options?  That way your C++ run-time-library comes from a DLL, too, which is the sort of picky thing VC++ is famous for.
2. Don't use throw-specs.  [They are evil](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm).  If you feel you must do it anyway, just put something like this in a header file that every module includes before it gets to code that uses throw-specs.

> #pragma warning(disable: 4290)

Comment: I am using /MD, doesn't help. Whacked all the ES's though, after reading the article, thanks.

Comment: More generally, then, you might download MySQL++ and take a look at its project settings to see why mine works and yours doesn't.  MySQL++ does something similar to your library: see lib/exceptions.h, where we derive a custom mysqlpp::Exception class from std::exception.

Comment: That's because apparently std::exception *is* exported in Microsoft-land. Changed mine to it, warnings are gone.

Comment: std::exception isn't exported in Microsoft-land anymore (Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 0):

First you should ask yourself if you really need a dynamic library here. Static libraries or or even better including the source code directly in your project is a good solution that comes without those problems.

If you really need the DLL, the way I would do this (given much time) is wrapping your class in a C interface. You can then recreate your old C++ interface as a C++ header only library that interacts only with the C calls exported from the DLL. A bonus feature for this approach is that it will be trivial to use your library from almost any programming language since importing C functions from DLL's is highly supported.

Another way to go would be to use COM but since you are porting from Linux this is probably not an option.